# Jackson polymorphic type conversion deletes the property after using it

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to use Jackson to automatically parse my JSON payload to subtypes

All is working as intended and the object is being parsed to the right subtype. but the property used for discriminating is deleted at the end of the process.

> ```
> @JsonTypeInfo(
>     use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
>     include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
>     property = "type")
> @JsonSubTypes({
>     @Type(value = MySubClass.class, name = "type1") })
> ```

In this case the property "type" is null in the MySubClass instance.

How do i tell jackson to leave the data intact.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; by default type information is considered to be metadata, and not data to expose to POJOs; similar to how Java type information is distinct from actual properties (albeit accessible via `getClass()`).

But you can expose type discriminator if you want to by using `@JsonTypeInfo(visible=true)`.

Comment: "visible=true" gives me compilation error. there is nothing like this.

Comment: OK, this is the right answer, just need to you jackson from "fasterxml".

Comment: @Gleeb Right, it is only available with Jackson 2.x, not 1.x.